# Trying to create instance of ChomeDriver throwing exception

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Starting yesterday 6/10/2016 my ChromeDriver tests are all failing when ran in my through TeamCity giving the following exception.

```
[Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:57539/session timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
```

Here is what my part of my `OneTimeSetUp` looks like

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver"))
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
    Driver = new TWebDriver();
    string s = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return navigator.userAgent;");
    log.Debug("Browser name/version: " + s);
```

I have verified by looking at my logs that I am not getting passed `Driver = new TWebDriver();`

Here is the stack trace in the my TeamCity build logs.

```
[10:51:34][Step 4/4] 1) TearDown Error : POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite<ChromeDriver>
[10:51:34][Step 4/4] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]   ----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:57539/session timed out after 60 seconds.
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]   ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
[10:51:34][Step 4/4] TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T]()
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite`1.SetUp() in c:\TCAgents\2\work\dbc32f79002d0c18\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\ExistingUserTestSuite.cs:line 49
[10:51:34][Step 4/4] --WebDriverException
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
[10:51:34][Step 4/4] --WebException
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
[10:51:34][Step 4/4]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
```

It looks to me like webdriver is failing to create an instance of ChromeDriver? When I run my tests locally through the NUnitConsoleRunner3.2.1 (the same way it is ran in TeamCity) tests run fine. It is only in teamcity that this issue happens. I do not have permissions to log into the server that they run on directly and check if there is something funky with Chrome I have asked someone on my DevOps team to take a look but am waiting on a response. Any help is greatly appreciated I really dont want to have these tests broken over the weekend I have trouble sleeping enough as is.

Comment: Try this: [Can't start c#+SeleniumWebDriver+Specflow+Nunit tests on Teamcity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37838121/4851443)

Comment: You can follow the bug here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615396

Answer (score 0):

The better way to clean up after your test is to destroy the driver after each test. I use following code for this:

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    var state = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.State;
    if (state == TestState.Error || state == TestState.Failure)
    {
        Utilities.Core.TakeScreenshot(this._chromeDriver, TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName);
    }

    _driver.Quit();
}
```

The upper part of this code is to capture the snapshot at the moment of error. It is very nice feature when you want to use TeamCity

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of the error below when your Selenium tests are running on your dev machine, but not in TeamCity:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote
>   WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:????/session timed out
>   after 60 seconds

is that your TeamCity is running as a Windows Service.

Stop the services "TeamCity Build Agent" and "TeamCity Server" and instead use the runAll.bat:

```
<TeamCity folder>\bin\runAll.bat start
```